# TFS Build error: C:\[path]\TFSBuild.proj (51): The local path 'C:\[path]\src' is not mapped to a TFS workspace

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

Trying to upgrade TFS 2013 to 2015.  Having an issue with the migrated XAML builds. Created a new build server and installed the build agent but am getting the error:

Getting sources

Labeling sources

Exception Message: TF270015: 'msbuild.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger "C:\Builds\16\[path]\Deploy-G.M.FunctionalTests\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" /m:1 /nr:False "@C:\Builds\16\[path]\Deploy-G.M.FunctionalTests\BuildType\TfsBuild.rsp"

Built $/[project]/Trunk/Tests/Builds/Deploy-G.M.FunctionalTests/TFSBuild.proj for default targets.

C:\Builds\16\[path]\Deploy-G.M.FunctionalTests\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj (51): The local path 'C:\Builds\16\[path]\Deploy-G.M.FunctionalTests\src' is not mapped to a TFS workspace.

Not sure why the the build working folder needs to be mapped to a TFS workspace.  This is a dynamic path and is specific to the build machine.

This is the part of the build project that causes the error:

```
<TfsChangeset LocalPath="$(SolutionRoot)" >
  <Output TaskParameter="Changeset" PropertyName="Revision"/>
</TfsChangeset>
<Message Text="TFS ChangeSet: $(Revision)" />
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue if you create a new build definition in TFS 2015?

Comment: You're not using a XAML build, you're using the XAML build engine to invoke an MSBuild build (ostensibly via the Upgrade Template), which was deprecated in TFS 2010. It's a good time to consider upgrading your build to use something a little bit more modern.

Comment: I can create new build definitions but at this stage I need the upgraded one to work.  Thanks @Daniel Mann.  That clarifies things a bit.  At this stage I need the current build to work.  I am not sure why I am getting "The local path  is not mapped to a TFS workspace error."  I have used the tf workfold command and it shows that the path is mapped to a workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I've only had this problem when I removed the Map under Mappings.  Do you have a Map type of Mapping?

[image]

Comment: I should have clafified that I am using XAML builds. The screen shot is for the new VS 2015 builds.  I am using XAML builds as I migrated the builds from 2013.  I do have the map set up in the Source Settings/Working Folders section of the XAML build.

Comment: Did you update your Build Process Template on the Process tab to the 2015 version?

Comment: The new Build process Template does not give me the options I need such as Configuration folder path and BuildToolsPath.